# How is it possible to preview a Minecraft world only by using its seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just wondering how different apps/websites do it only by using world seed.

Like Minecraft seed map viewer.

Comment: The question is how these websites do it - please don't VTC this as asking for recommendations of those websites.

Comment: Like chunkbase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the game has to generate a new world, it calls upon an algorithm that outputs a pseudo-random value that is then used to determine the characteristics and features of the world. However, the algorithm always outputs the same set of values each time for a constant starting point (the **seed**). Thus, the same seed generates the same terrain with the same structures every time.

Minecraft Java is written in Java, and it's possible to decompile and unobfuscate the source code behind the world generation (which is done through tools like [MCP](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Mod_Coder_Pack)).

Online websites exploit this, and once biomes and structures are calculated they are only shown on screen.